# Makefile Difficulties

Tags: c, makefile

Makefiles are confusing to me. All I am trying to do is separate off some functions into a separate file, but I can't get it to compile. What am I missing? Thanks!

Makefile:

```
all: clientfunctions client

clientfunctions.o: clientfunctions.c
    gcc -c clientfunctions.c -o clientfunctions.o

client.o: client.c clientfunctions.o
    gcc -c client.c -o client.o

client: client.o
    gcc client.o -o client
```

The .c and .h files are also very simple:

clientfunctions.h

```
#ifndef _clientfunctions_h
#define _clientfunctions_h
#endif

void printmenu();
```

clientfunctions.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "clientfunctions.h"

void printmenu() {
    fprintf(stdout, "Please select one of the following options\n");
}
```

client.c

```
#include "clientfunctions.h"

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printmenu();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [clientfunctions] Error 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
all: client

clientfunctions.o: clientfunctions.c
    gcc -c clientfunctions.c -o clientfunctions.o

client.o: client.c 
    gcc -c client.c -o client.o

client: client.o clientfunctions.o
    gcc client.o clientfunctions.o -o client
```

Here is more idiomatic way to write this Makefile.

```
all: client

client: client.o clientfunctions.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: That was it. Having both clientfunctions and client in the all: section seemed to cause the trouble. Thank you.

Comment: Please see edit for a better way to write the Makefile. Don't forget to accept an answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile both .c files and link them both into your executable.  You need a dependency on `clientfunctions.o` in your `client` target and to include this object in your link to do this

```
client: client.o clientfunctions.o
    gcc client.o clientfunctions.o -o client
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I also needed to remove `clientfunctions` from the all: line.

Comment: Yes, if you don't specify a target, make will default to the first one it finds, starting from the top of your base makefile.  This is `all` in your case.  It currently declares two dependencies; one of these - `clientfunctions` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You are working *way* too hard.  You can rely on implicit rules and greatly simplify your makefile, whose entire contents can (probably, depending on which Make you are using) be as simple as:

```
client: client.o clientfunctions.o
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say actually what is wrong, besides "I can't get it to compile" which tells us essentially nothing.  Try providing an error message or something next time.

However, this doesn't have anything to do with make.  The next time you think you're having a makefile problem, just cut and past the commands into your shell prompt.  If they work, then your problem is with make.  If they don't work, then your problem is with your compile commands and you should look at the documentation for your compiler to solve it.  Make is fundamentally a tool for running shell commands, in the proper order and at the proper time.

In your case, you need to add the `-c` option to your compile line if you want to generate an object file.  Without that option, the compiler will try to generate an executable.